# What approach is better of using date truncate?

Tags: java, date, jdbc

What approach is better?

**1.**

```
String sql = "select count(*) from table where date = trunc(?, 'DD')";

getJdbcTemplate().queryForInt(sql, new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()))
```

**2.**

```
String sql = "select count(*) from table where date = ?";

getJdbcTemplate().queryForInt(sql, new java.sql.Date(DateUtils.truncate(date, Calendar.DATE).getTime()))
```

Comment: Could you find any difference in their performance and i would go with 1

Answer (score 0):

I will prefer `date = trunc(?, 'DD')` as it wont need extra third party `DateUtils` to perform the truncate operation.
Don't think their will be a noticable impact on performance if you use any of the 2